# Best way to locate link with protractor

Tags: selenium, user-interface, testing, protractor

```js
<a href="someCoolLinkText.com">
    <h3 class="main-header"> 
        COOL LINK 
    </h3>
 </a>
```

What is best way to find and click on this link?

Comment: *best way to do something* is not kind of questions you should ask on SO - such questions should be closed as **primarily opinion-based**

Answer (score 2):

Try to locate required node by its link text:

```
element(by.linkText('COOL LINK')).click()
```

Note that you should use text exactly as it appears on page, but not as it appears in HTML source code

*Update*

You can try to use [ExpectedCondition](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorExpectedConditions.prototype.elementToBeClickable) to wait for link appearance in DOM:

```
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(element(by.linkText('COOL LINK'))), 5000).click();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have tried this way. "Failed: No element found using locator: By(link text, COO LINK) ; also used by.partialLinkText. It's same.

Comment: Try updated answer. Actually I'm not sure about it's correctness as I have no practice with Protractor for a long time...

Comment: @Manta, I have seen in the error log, that you have missed out "L", It supposed to be "COOL LINK"

Answer (score 0):

You can use this xpath :- `//h3[text()='COOL LINK']`

Answer (score 0):

The text **COOL LINK** is within `<h3>` tag so you can use `xpath` as :

```
//a[@href='someCoolLinkText.com']/h3[@class='main-header' and contains(.,'COOL LINK')]
```